# Finding consecutive 00's and 11's in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, division

I have a vector `a = 1111000011100001110000100100` and I have to compute two values based on it: `p00` and `p11`.

`p00` is the number of times `00` is occurring in the vector, divided by the total number of zeros. For example, in the above code then number of times `00` is occurring is `8/16` (total number of zeros).

Similarly, `p11` is the number of occurrences of `11` divided by the total number of ones.

How can this be implemented in Matlab?

Comment: Your question is not totally clear. I count 11 that is more than 8 `00` entries in your vector. Must a `0` only appear once in each `00` pair?

Comment: I think that the test case shows that all pairs must be non-overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest and most generic way to do it is using regular expressions, because of the way they match runs.

```
a = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
s = char(a + '0');
p00 = numel(regexp(s, '00')) / sum(a == 0)
p11 = numel(regexp(s, '11')) / sum(a == 1)
```

**NOTE**:
I was tempted to do something along the following lines:

```
a = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
n = numel(a);
p00 = sum(a(1:n-1) == 0 & a(2:n) == 0) / sum(a == 0)
p11 = sum(a(1:n-1) == 1 & a(2:n) == 1) / sum(a == 1)
```

But this won't give the correct result, because it counts the sequence `0 0 0 0` as 3, rather than 2.

Comment: thank you very much for replying, but when i run this i am getting this error "??? Undefined function or method 'regexp' for input arguments of type 'double'". any idea would be very much appreciated. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: thank you mate. But how will i do that? how will i use a=char(a + '0') in the code? and where?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the vector to itself shifted with one element to the right. The number of two-s will be the number of 11-s. The number of 0-s will be the number of 00-s. I think this is a natural solution in MATLAB.

Alternatively you could implement finite state machines to parse your vector.

```
a2  = a(2:end)+a(1:end-1);
p11 = length(find(a2 == 2))/length(find(a));
p00 = length(find(a2 == 0))/length(find(a==0));
```

Comment: i am not getting the appropriate answer from this code, from the example above the value of p00 should be 0.5 but i am getting 0.7. and for a very long series i get infinity. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This won't work for the same reason that my alternative solution doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution was wrong!!!

Here is one that should work, but is not very efficient (but faster than the `regexp` solution):

```
d0=0; i=1; 
while i<length(a) 
    if (a(i) == 0 & a(i)==a(i+1)) d0 = d0+1; i = i+1; end; 
    i=i+1;
end
p00 = d0/sum(a == 0)
```

Comment: thank u very much mate!! it's working awesome!! but what if i have to do find p11? how should i do that?? thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. `a = [0 0]` should give `p00 = 0.5`, but this code gives `p00 = 1`.

Comment: @Nzbuu: I have said that in the answer.

Comment: @Boris, I didn't see that. However, `a = [ 0 0 0 0 0 ]` should give `p00 = 0.4`, but this code gives `p00 = 0.6`.

Comment: @Nzbuu: Yes, you are right, the code is wrong! I see the mistake I have made.